# Javascript - Random Color Function (control brightness and contrast)

Tags: javascript, random, colors, brightness

Few days ago I started to search for a JavaScript function that generate random colors.

I found a script and made some changes of my own:

```
function getRandColor(brightness)
{
    //6 levels of brightness from 0 to 5, 0 being the darkest
    var rgb = [Math.random() * 256, Math.random() * 256, Math.random() * 256];
    var mix = [brightness*51, brightness*51, brightness*51]; //51 => 255/5
    var mixedrgb = [rgb[0] + mix[0], rgb[1] + mix[1], rgb[2] + mix[2]].map(function(x){ return Math.round(x/2.0)})    
    var rgb = mixedrgb[2] | (mixedrgb[1] << 8) | (mixedrgb[0]  << 16);
    return  '#' + rgb.toString(16);
}
```

I would like add a contrast parameter to the function. How can this be done?

Also, If you think there is a faster way to do the calculations, please share. Thanks.

---

After a lot of search and testing (because I am very bad in this colors things) I made a function to convert hsl to hex color. I am using hsl because it is much easy to work with hsl properties to make the colors you want.

The Function is really bad and ugly, so help me to make it better. For, example the random function returns duplicate values even in 100 calls.

```
  function RandomValue(MinValue,MaxValue)
{
    return parseInt(Math.random()*(MaxValue-MinValue+1), 10)+MinValue;
}

function GetRandomColor()
{
    var h = RandomValue(1, 360);   // color hue between 1 and 360
    var s = RandomValue(20, 100);  // saturation 0-100%
    var l = RandomValue(50, 70);   // lightness  0-70%

    /* Convert the HSL values to HEX */

    return HSLtoRGB(h, s, l);
}

function HSLtoRGB(h, s, v)
{
    var r, g, b;
    var i;
    var f, p, q, t;

    h = Math.max(0, Math.min(360, h));
    s = Math.max(0, Math.min(100, s));
    v = Math.max(0, Math.min(100, v));

    s /= 100;
    v /= 100;

    if(s == 0) 
    {
        r = g = b = v;
        return [Math.round(r * 255), Math.round(g * 255), Math.round(b * 255)];
    }

    h /= 60; 
    i = Math.floor(h);
    f = h - i; 
    p = v * (1 - s);
    q = v * (1 - s * f);
    t = v * (1 - s * (1 - f));

    switch(i) 
    {
        case 0:
        r = v;
        g = t;
        b = p;
        break;

        case 1:
        r = q;
        g = v;
        b = p;
        break;

        case 2:
        r = p;
        g = v;
        b = t;
        break;

        case 3:
        r = p;
        g = q;
        b = v;
        break;

        case 4:
        r = t;
        g = p;
        b = v;
        break;

        default: 
        r = v;
        g = p;
        b = q;
    }

    var rgb = Math.round(b * 255) | (Math.round(g * 255) << 8) | (Math.round(r * 255)  << 16);

    var m=rgb.toString(16);

    switch(m.length)
    {
        case 5:return  '#' + rgb.toString(16) + '0';break;
        case 4:return  '#' + rgb.toString(16) + '00';break;
        default:return  '#' + rgb.toString(16);break;
    }
}


for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.backgroundColor = GetRandomColor() ;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: Contrast can only exist against something else.  So how would you set the contrast of just a single color?

Comment: Do you not mean saturation and lightness?